# Unable to download flexmojos plugin, maven ignores repositories config

Tags: apache-flex, maven, maven-plugin, flexmojos

I have Flex project and I need flexmojos-maven-plugin to build it.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
    <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
</plugin>
```

I also mentioned repository

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>flexmojos</id>
        <url>http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But maven ignores it and doesn't try to download plugin from there.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/flexmojos/flexmojos-maven-plugin/3.9/flexmojos-maven-plugin-3.9.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:3.9' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
```

Please, advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with the 3.9 build. I can successfully download version 3.8 without any problems. But 3.9 triggers an "unable to find resource" error.

I doubt you've had problems resolving the repositories. Sometimes the Maven output doesn't do a great job of showing its efforts it reading from remote repos. Particularly when you repeatedly run the same failing command (e.g. `mvn clean install`).

Take a look in your local repository. If you can find anything under `org/sonatype/flexmojos` then you're certainly resolving the repository correctly.

I would suggest you post this on the mailing list: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/Project+Information

Comment: Wow, miracle. Changed version to 3.8 and it's working! Thanks a lot!